# Meraki API with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

Referring to the Github content. https://github.com/meraki/dashboard-api-python/blob/master/meraki.py

Assuming that I just want to list the networks in my organization. I have identified the sample template required. How and where do i execute this script? Do i just put this into a file and rename it as .py , following which executing it from my terminate?

```
> # List the networks in an organization
> # https://api.meraki.com/api_docs#list-the-networks-in-an-organization def getnetworklist(apikey, orgid, templateid=None,
> suppressprint=False):
>     #
>     # Confirm API Key has Admin Access Otherwise Raise Error
>     #
>     __hasorgaccess(apikey, orgid)
>     calltype = 'Network'
> 
>     geturl = '{0}/organizations/{1}/networks'.format(
>         str(base_url), str(orgid))
>     if templateid is not None:
>         geturl += '?configTemplateId=' + templateid
>     headers = {
>         'x-cisco-meraki-api-key': format(str(apikey)),
>         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>     }
>     dashboard = requests.get(geturl, headers=headers)
>     #
>     # Call return handler function to parse Dashboard response
>     #
>     result = __returnhandler(
>         dashboard.status_code, dashboard.text, calltype, suppressprint)
>     return result
```

Comment: not sure whats going on here, but `suppressprint=False):` isn't proper syntax

Comment: @SuperStew, i am just confused as to how to i call the information. Do i need to build a function? Or can i just pack this into a .py file and attempt to run it from my terminal.